# Unpacking the `\begin{abstract}` Command and Customising It

Tags: abstract

In other questions on tex.SE regarding the abstract, I have seen someone say what the `abstract` command does. However, I cannot for the life of me now find it!
I want to make my own version that is similar, and use this as a basepoint.

I think it's something like the following.

```
\begin{quotation} \small
    {\centering \bfseries Abstract\par}
    [body of abstract]
\end{quotation}
```

I'm not sure if this is giving exactly the desired spacing---in particular, the vertical spacing seems a little off...

I would like to make my own customised environment.

```
\newenvironment{customabstract}
    {\begin{quotation} \centering \bfseries \sffamily Abstract\par\smallskip}
    {\end{quotation}}
```

It seems to me that if I don't use `\small` then one should add the `\smallskip`. This is just guesswork, though.
I would also like to be able to remove the indent (after all, no style guide of which I am aware says that abstracts start indented). However, wherever I add `\noindent`, I seem to get a small additional space (ie the first word is not flush to the left). Note that I don't want to replace `quotation` with `quote`, as I want the remaining paragraphs to be indented and without the extra space between paragraphs from `quote`.

If this is not correct, can someone correct it for me?

Comment: The original definition in the `article` class can be found in `article.cls` or in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf.

Comment: Assuming that your are not using the `titlepage` option and that you are in one-column mode, `abstract` is roughly defined as `\newenvironment{abstract}
  {\small
   \begin{center}%
     {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
   \end{center}%
   \quotation}
  {\endquotation}` (modulo line breaks)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'm not sure why these are comments not answers? Are these only comments not answers as they do not answer the part about `\noindent`? Would you like me to copy the info from the link into a (partial) answer? `:)`

Comment: It wasn't too clear to me what answer you are looking for. I can certainly collect the comments into an answer and flesh them out a bit if you like.

Comment: I was happy to collect it together so as to not use your time, but wouldn't have been able to explain it well like you have. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the standard classes is documented in [`classes.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf). Together with [`source2e.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) this should cover most of the stuff that is defined when you just say `\documentclass{article}`.

The relevant definition for `abstract` is

```
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
```

This shows that the definition is different when the `tilepage` option is set.

Assuming you have not set the `titlepage` option and you don't have `twocolumn` mode active, `abstract` can be simplified to

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
   \small
   \begin{center}%
     {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
   \end{center}%
   \quotation}
  {\endquotation}
```

or

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
   \small
   \begin{center}%
     {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
   \end{center}%
   \begin{quotation}}
  {\end{quotation}}
```

---

Depending on what exactly you want you could remove the first paragraph indent in `abstract` like so

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{noindentabstract}{%
   \small
   \begin{center}%
     {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
   \end{center}%
   \begin{quotation}\noindent\ignorespaces}
  {\end{quotation}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{noindentabstract}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{noindentabstract}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks!